# Property of a holomorphic function with a zero of order $n$ at $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

**Notation:**

Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb C$ be an open set. Let $Z:=\{z_i\}_{i=0}^N$, $N \in \Bbb N$, denote the set of poles of a function $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$, with $g, h$ holomorphic near $z_0$. Let $f$ be continuous on $\overline{\Omega} \backslash Z$ and holomorphic on $\Omega \backslash Z$.

---

I'd like to prove the following statement:

> If $h(z)$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and has a zero of order $n$ at $z_0 \in \Omega$, then there exists a function $\phi$, holomorphic on $\Omega$, such that $\frac{1}{h(z)} = \frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^n}$, with $\phi(z_0) \neq 0$.

**My attempt:**

Since $h$ is holomorphic, $h$ is analytic and can be written as

$$h(z) = \sum_{k \geq 0} a_k (z-z_0)^k$$

on the disk $D(z_0,r)$, where $r \leq R$ is sufficiently small, such that $ D(z_0,r) \subset \Omega$. ($R$ denotes the radius of convergence of the power series.) Since $h(z)$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z_0$, we have

$$a_0 = a_1 = \dots = a_{n-1} = 0$$

It follows

\begin{align*}
h(z) &= \sum_{k \geq n} a_k (z-z_0)^k \\
&= \sum_{k \geq 0} a_{k+n} (z-z_0)^{k+n} \\
&= (z-z_0)^n \sum_{k \geq 0} a_{k+n} (z-z_0)^k =: (z-z_0)^n \tilde{h}(z)
\end{align*}

By the definition of $\tilde{h}(z)$ we see that $\exists \rho > 0$ such that $\tilde{h}(z) \neq 0$ on $D(z_0,\rho)$, since at least $a_n \neq 0$. Thus we may set $\phi(z) = \frac{1}{\tilde{h}(z)}$, which is then obviously holomorphic on $D(z_0,\rho)$ and $\phi(z_0) \neq 0$ since $\tilde{h}(z)$ is holomorphic on $D(z_0,r)$ and thus has no singularities there. This yields the desired result, i.e.

$$\frac{1}{h(z)} = \frac{1}{(z-z_0)^n \tilde{h}(z)} = \frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^n} \qquad \Box$$

Could someone please verify it, because I'm not entirely sure about it. (Alternative proofs of the statement above are also very appreciated.)

EDIT: Thanks to the comment of Daniel Fischer. I corrected some minor inaccuracies.

Comment: I'd recommend you state your definition of zero of order $n$, since some people would say that the statement you are proving is the definition.

Comment: You can't deduce that $\tilde{h}$ has no zeros on $D(z_0,r)$. You only know that there is a $\rho > 0$ such that $\tilde{h}$ has no zeros on $D(z_0,\rho)$ (since $\tilde{h}(z_0) = a_n \neq 0$), in general, $\rho$ will be strictly smaller than $r$. And in the representation $\frac{1}{h(z)} = \frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^n}$, $\phi$ is usually not holomorphic on all of $\Omega$, it has poles at the other zeros of $h$ (but $\phi$ will be _meromorphic_ on $\Omega$). And you wrote "$a_k \neq 0$ for $k \geq n$", but you only know that $a_n \neq 0$.

Comment: Ok, so concerning $\phi$ you claim that the statement is inaccurate? It is from an old exercise sheet (from a faculty of physics), which I use for self-studying.

Comment: @Chappers out of curiosity who does this? And what is the rational to pass to the reciprocal?